# how to create portal page urls in wcm

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm, ibm-content-navigator, ibm-wcm

How i can create URL of a portal page in WCM. I tried URLCmpnt tag but it actually generate URL for content who want to get render on given portalTarget.

This is a very common scenario but not getting any clue.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is if your site area or content is part of the content association of a page, then you link to the content it should take you to the page url